# Geolocation: Tutorial on plotting numerous users on map?

Tags: geolocation

Can someone can refer me to a tutorial or such that provides information regarding how to capture a users location and plot other users around them?  I'm hoping to build an app that contains a functionality for you to open the app on the phone and see other users within a set radius that are also running the app.  All help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very hard to help without knowing which programming language you are interested in.

But here goes a page for an example that uses python and javascript:

http://www.goldb.org/geo_maps/

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I'm using PHP.

Comment: Does anyone have information on how to achieve the this using HTML5 and PHP?  I'm newbie to this, so I'm assuming I'd need to use Google Geolocation APIs or such to pass/capture multiple user locations and plot them? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use node.js. There is a screencast (not free) about how to do exactly such a thing:
http://peepcode.com/products/nodejs-i